# The use of "precisely"

Tags: word-usage

> There are various ways in which something can be wrong, but in this
> case, if you had to explain it, you'd probably say that it would be
> unfair to other users of the library who may be just as interested in
> the book as your friend is, but who consult it in the reference room,
> where anyone who needs it can find it. You may also feel that to let
> him take it would betray your employers, who are paying you **precisely**
> to keep this sort of thing from happening.

What does it all mean, Thomas Nagel, Chapter VII

I don't know the use of "precisely" in the context above. Which word does it modify? "paying" or "keep"?

Answer (score 3):

It modifies 'to keep this sort of thing from happening'! Presumably the passage refers to illicit borrowing of library books. Library staff are employed *for the specific purpose* of controlling the loan of books and making sure that reference books don't leave the library.